# How can I write this in a different way so that the fixture is not called always?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

My test suite has a fixture shared by all tests.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def foo_fixture():
    data = get_data()
    if not data:
        pytest.fail('ERROR: Could not get data', pytrace=False)
```

Then I have a lot of tests which basically boil down to:

```
def test_foo(foo_fixture):
    assert something, pytest.fail('ERROR: ...', pytrace=False)

def test_bar(foo_fixture):
    assert something, pytest.fail('ERROR: ...', pytrace=False)
```

The issue I'm seeing is that whenever `get_data()` returns nothing, the fixture is called by every test. Why do I know this? Because the output is:

```
____________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_foo ____________________________________________________________________
ERROR: Could not get data
____________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_bar____________________________________________________________________
ERROR: Could not get data
```

As you can see, I'm setting the fixture with `scope="session"`, so it should run only once. I think the problem here is the `pytest.fail`. I guess it's ending the session, so that's why the fixture is called all the times.

So, how could I write this in a different way so that the fixture is called only once? When `get_data()` actually returns something, I can notice the fixture is running only once due to tests duration. But as I said, when there is no data, it runs for every test, and the problem is that `get_data()` does many requests to different APIs, so I want to run it just once for lowering tests duration.

Comment: It looks like `get_data` returns `None` on every call. Since you have `pytest.fail` in the fixture, an exception is raised, so the return value of `foo_fixture` can't be stored in session. That's why the calls for `foo_fixture`'s value are repeated. Once `get_data` returns something meaningful and no error is raised, the return value of `foo_fixture` will be stored in session and it won't be called anymore.

Comment: use 'yield' (e.g. yield data) instead of 'return' to turn the function into a generator, so it gets called only once

Comment: @hoefling `get_data` returns an empty list, not a `None`. I just checked something. Before the `if` I added a `print(type(data))`, and it's printed only once, that means, the fixture is called only once as I expected. Now, what I don't understand then, is why I'm seeing the message of the `pytest.fail` per each test then.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is returned, `None`, `False`, `0` or an empty list. But it means that the exception raised on first fixture call is stored, so the fixture is indeed evaluated only once; subsequent requests for the `foo_fixture` value return the exception stored on first call. It is enough for `get_data` to return nothing on first request; it won't be called anymore. This behaviour is indeed the correct one, so no error on `pytest` side here.

Comment: @hoefling ok, understood. That qualifies as an answer IMO.